# Induction proofs

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

So the question is; Using mathematical induction that for all $n \geq 1$, the sum of the squares of the first $2n$ positive integers is given by the formula:

$$1^2+2^2+3^2...+(2n)^2 = \frac{n(2n+1)(4n+1)}{3}$$

So I did the base case of $P(1) =5$, but $(2(1))^2=4$.

I can do the rest of the proof once I figure out what's wrong with my base case, there must be something I'm not seeing. I did $P(1)-P(4)$ and no matter what they are never equal. What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks Guys!

Comment: I don't see the problem? $1^2 + 2^2 = 1 + 4 = 5$ and $1\cdot3\cdot5/3 = 5$.

Comment: When $n=1$ both the left and right sides equal $5$, so what's the problem?

Comment: Show (in excruciating detail) exactly why $P(1)$ should equal $(2(1))^2$, with explanation for every step. At some point we'll be able to spot what you missed.

Comment: so I computed P(1) by doing (1(2(1)+1)(4(1)+1))/3 which = 5 and I then did (2(1))^2 = 4.  I see everyone is saying that it would be 1^2 + (2(n))^2 instead of just (2(n))^2 so that must be my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what does that $(2(1))^2$ signify here but the reasoning follow like this:

Since you are talking about square of first $2n$ numbers so the base case ask to compute you the sum of square of $1$ and $2$ which is $1+4=5$ and the result is same when you plug $n=1 $ in $$\frac{n(2n+1)(4n+1)}{3}$$

Comment: Awesome man!  I think I just completely misread the question now, thanks for the answer I'm onto the induction proof of it now, I'll ask if I need any help.  Thanks again!

Comment: No problem @IanMcmahon

Comment: so far by trying to show P(k+1) I ended up getting (k(2k+1)(4k+1))/3 + (2(k+1))^2/1 which I then made (6(k+1))^2/3  I just want to make sure my algebra is right before I continue going down all this paper lol

Comment: Well I don't understand what you are asking @IanMacmahon are you asking for a complete inductive proof?

Comment: yes the question is to give a full inductive proof but I'm stuck at the algebra, which I always get stuck at.

Answer (score 0):

For $n = 1,$ the sum of squares of the first $2n$ positive integers is
the sum of squares of the first *two* positive integers,
$$ 1^2 + 2^2 = 5.$$

For $n = 2,$ the sum of squares of the first $2n$ positive integers is
the sum of squares of the first $2(2) = 4$ positive integers,
$$ 1^2 + 2^2 +3^2 + 4^2 = 30.$$

The $2n$ tells you that you always stop adding squares at the square of an even number, but it does *not* say you should skip the odd numbers.
Even the problem statement itself shows that you were meant to
include the squares of the odd numbers in your sum: 
$1^2,$ $3^2,$ and so forth.